# Automatic Google Indexing

Tags: seo, search-engine

Implemented Google site search  in our company website. We need to automate the google indexing for our website.

Suppose like our customers are updated the forum. We need to show the up to updated forum information in our forum search ?

Is there any option in google API or any other API please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/). This will tell the search engines where your content is so they can find it and crawl it. Keep in mind there is no way to make the search engines crawl your site when *you* want them to. They will crawl on a schedule they determine to be right for your site. (You can set a crawl rate in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) but that rate is relative to what crawl rate Google already has set for you. Setting it to fastest will not speed up heir crawl rate)).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google will only crawl your site when it feels like it. It is based on many variables to determine how often this occurs (i.e. site ranking, standards compliance, and so on). The sitemap XML is a helpful way to help Google determine what parts of your site to index, however if you don't have one Google will find it by crawling links on other parts of your page and updating its index if the page changes.

The more visitors you get and the more often your site's links appear on other sites will make Google index more frequently.

To start, I'd suggest http://validator.w3.org/ to validate your site and make sure you get it as close to possible to no errors. This makes it easier for Google to index your site because it can find the information it expects without having to crawl over invalid markup. Also, chances are, if a site validates with a very small amount of errors, it is more credible than one containing many errors. It tells the search engine that you update your site to ensure most all browsers can use it and that it is accessible.

Also validating your site gives you some bragging rights over those who don't meet W3 standards :)

Hope this helps!